# Force iPhone to use cellular data while connected to wifi

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data

I have an iPhone 5s with iOS 7 on T-mobile in the US. I have a wifi network that is not connected to the Internet. When I connect to the wifi network with my phone, my iPhone tries to access the Internet using wifi only instead of using cellular data. Of course my phone cannot access the Internet using the wifi network because the network is not connected to the Internet. However it should be able to use cellular data.

How can I force my phone to use cellular data to access the Internet while connected to a wifi network?

Comment: sorry, what exactly is holding you back from turning the WiFi off ?

Comment: I want to use AirPlay.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, as shown here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6448960?start=0&tstart=0

As the link describes, use a static IP in the wifi network but only fill in the IP and Subnet Mask fields.

Edit: this is also answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174722/120252

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is not possible (my internet has gone out enough times in the last few weeks that I've tried).

If your carrier allows Personal Hotspot, however, you can turn it on and have the AirPlay device connect to the network the phone creates, and then AirPlay will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this. My data plan is in two pools: hotspot (limited) and mobile (unlimited). Do you know which pool will be used if using Personal Hotspot while on wifi?

Comment: I've never heard of that being separated, but I would guess that the airplay device would use hotspot (but it wouldn't have to connect to the internet much, if at all) and the phone would continue being mobile.