# Can I connect to wifi but still use cellular?

Tags: iphone, wifi, settings, cellular-data

I would like to be able to connect to my cars dashcam via wifi while in the car but still be able to use my iPhone's cellular connection.

The way the dashcam works, it appears as a wifi access point so the phone tries to connect to the Internet through it. How can I be connected to the access point while still using my phones cellular?

Comment: What happens when you actually try to do this? In any case, the wifi and cell signals do not interfere with each other, and both should work without problems. YMMV.

Comment: When I'm connected to the dashcam via wifi, the iPhone tries to connect to the Internet via the wifi access point, I want to connect to the wifi access point but still be able to use the Internet via my cellular connection.

Comment: You didn't mention a wifi access point was in the car, only a wifi webcam. Please edit your question to include this important point.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this is possible!...

Use the following instructions:
1. Tap the blue arrow next to the name of the AirPort Express WiFi network to view more options.
2. Select "Static" as the type of IP address, and then enter the following IP address and Subnet Mask :

IP Address : 10.0.1.4 (for example)
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0

Make sure you leave Router, DNS, and Search Domains blank! This tells the iPhone that it should use its cellular network to route internet traffic rather than trying to do it via WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible ([as discovered here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207060/148130))

1. Connect to device's wifi
2. Make note of the DHCP `IP address` and `Subnetmask`
3. And use those values with `Static` IP

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible to work with both the backup camera Wi-Fi and LTE at the same time -- I just did it.  The problem of having the connection to my Wi-Fi back-up camera blocking my internet use over the cell towers has driven me crazy.  The solution is so easy it is embarassing.

These folks are right.  Just follow these easy steps:

1. Connect your iPhone to the Wi-Fi for your backup camera.
2. Go to SETTINGS and select Wi-Fi then select the blue INFO icon to the right of the name of your back-up camera Wi-Fi
3. Make note of both the IP address and the Subnet Mask address
4. Select the STATIC option and enter only the IP and Subnet Mask addresses from Step 3 -- (Leave everything else blank)

Your iPhone will be connected to your back-up camera Wi-Fi and also to the LTE signal at the same time.  SIRI and all internet functions (Weather, Navigation, Inquiries, etc) will continue to work with the LTE signal while simultaneously enjoying the safety of your back-up camera.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can make calls or receive texts while connected to the hotspot, then yes, you can!

However, if you're asking if you can use cellular internet, then I'm afraid that is not possible.

*(Mildly technical explanation ahead!)* The reason is that, when connected to WiFi, the iPhone funnels all requests through that Wifi connection to the dashcam's built-in server. Now, some apps are programmed to switch to cellular if the connection times out, but this takes a not-insignificant amount of time and is contingent on how the dashcam responds to these requests sent by these other apps (e.g. 404 error vs. DNS lookup failure). *(End technical explanation)*

Sorry that this probably isn't the news that you wanted, but I hoped it helped to clarify the issue!